# Outlook 2010 not letting me open a link from an email

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

When I am in Outlook 2010 and I receive an email with a link I am not able to click on that link and go directly to the internet.  When I click on the link this is what comes up:  "This operation has been canceled due to restrictions in effect on this computer.  Please contact your system administrator.  It is a laptop that runs windows 7.  I recently removed Trend Micro and installed Windows Systems Essentials as my antivirus protector.

Can someone help??

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to un-installing Google Chrome which failed to clean up after itself. Try this:

Automated Solution:

1. Download and run Fix it located on this page http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049

Alternate/Manual Solution:

1. **Start**, click **Run**, type `regedit` in the Open box, and then click **OK**.
2. Browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.html`
3. Right click the value for the `.html` key and select **Modify…**
4. Change the value from `ChromeHTML` to `htmlfile` (or from `FireFoxHTML` to `htmlfile`)
5. Repeat for each of the `.htm`, `.shtml`, `.xht`, `.xhtml`, `.xhtm` keys

Source: http://www.slipstick.com/problems/this-operation-has-been-cancelled-due-to-restrictions/#reg2